# If string is ... then replace it with an image?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following piece of code:

```
<?php echo get_custom_field('Services'); ?>
```

There are three possible string outputs for this: "food", "drink", "food & drink".

I would like to replace these strings with small icons (e.g. a glass for "drink").

Is there a simple way of doing this with PHP?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could map the values via an array:

```
$items = array(
    "Food" => "plate.png",
    "Drink" => "glass.png",
    "Food & Drink" => "tray.png"
);
```

Then perform your look-up when echoing the image:

```
<img src="<?php echo $items[ get_custom_field('Services') ]; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use switch:

```
<?php
        switch (get_custom_field('Services')) {
                case "glass":
                        echo '<img src="glass.jpg" />';
                break;
                case "drink":
                        echo '<img src="food.jpg" />';
                break;
                case "food & drink":
                        echo '<img src="food-drink.jpg" />';
                break;
                default:
                        echo '<img src="noicon.jpg" />';
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer, but I would add a class to the (containing...) element and use css to remove the text and show a background image:

php:

```
<?php echo '<span class="' . $SERVICES_ID_OR_SOMETHING . '">' . get_custom_field('Services') . '</span>'; ?>
```

css:

```
.SERVICES_ID_OR_SOMETHING {
  background: url(/path/to/image) no-repeat left center;
  text-indent: -9999em;
}
```

Comment: @jeroen This should be a comment.

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson It is an alternative - and in my opinion better - solution to the problem the OP is having.

Comment: @jeroen It's not an alternative, IMHO. It doesn't address the problem of mapping one value to another. It's definitely good advice, but it's lacking the core component of how to determine which icon based on the value.

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson I agree it needs some fine-tuning in the `$SERVICES_ID_OR_SOMETHING` department, but as your solution was already there and the OP seems to prefer it anyway I'll leave it to future readers to combine the two if necessary :)