# Wordpress PHP - replace string with string

Tags: php, wordpress

So im using Wordpress advanced custom fields, outpit is this:

```
<?php the_field('output'); ?>
```

Output is pure text, it can be: one, two or three. I need to replace output text with image.

I tried this example: [if string...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102661/if-string-is-then-replace-it-with-an-image) but its not working for me. I also tried swithc example on the bottom of that link but still not working. Probobly couse they use litlle bit diferent output. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use get_field() rather that the_field().

As per your linked question:

```
    $items = array(
    "one" => "one.png",
    "two" => "two.png",
    "three" => "three.png"
);


<img src="<?php echo $items[ get_field('output') ]; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use a select field because you cannot force the users to add specific values with a textfield.

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/select/

And than do it like user574632's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Advanced Custom Fields, but if it has no equivalent `get` function for `the_field()` (which would surprise me), then you could use the following method (obviously filling in the `src` and `alt` attributes as required).

```
<?php
ob_start();
the_field('output');
$result = ob_get_clean();

switch($result) :

    case 'one' :
        echo '<img src="" alt="" />';
        break;
    case 'two' :
        echo '<img src="" alt="" />';
        break;
    case 'three' :
        echo '<img src="" alt="" />';
        break;

endswitch;
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

From what I understand about WordPress, functions like `the_title()` and `the_content()` just echo the content out directly, but usually have a corresponding `get_the_*` function that returns the value instead. `the_field()` has `get_field()`. So you can capture it in a variable and use it in a `switch` statement:

```
<?php
$output = get_field('output');

switch ($output) {
    case 'one':
        // first image
    break;
    case 'two':
        // second image
    break;
    case 'three':
        // third image
    break;
}
```